# Comparing two different CSV files with headers and export difference to new CSV with dates

Tags: python, csv

So I have two `CSV` files; one large data file and one file with all the National Holidays. Therefore, the headers are not identical (as the `NH` file only has one column). What I'm trying to do is filter the large data file by these National Holidays, and if it is a match (which will happen as it is yearly data), the row will not be exported to the new `CSV` file. I've tried many things but nothing will give me the desired output. Both files do have the same date notation `YYYY-MM-DD`.

```py
import csv

f1 = open('file1.csv')
oldFile1 = csv.reader(f1)
oldList1 = []
for row in oldFile1:
    oldList1.append(row)

f2 = open('file2.csv')
oldFile2 = csv.reader(f2)
oldList2 = []
for row in oldFile2:
    oldList2.append(row)

f1.close()
f2.close()

keyfield = 1 # Change this for choosing the column number

oldList2keys = [row['Date'] for row in oldList2]
print ([row for row in oldList1 if row['Date'] not in oldList2keys])
```

So what I have now:

file1.csv

```
A,B,C,D
11,7,12231,2014-06-07
23,11,12243,2014-06-08
35,15,12256,2014-06-09
47,19,12270,2014-06-10
59,23,12282,2014-06-11
71,27,12295,2014-06-12
83,31,12309,2014-06-13
95,35,12321,2014-06-14
107,39,12334,2014-06-15
119,43,12348,2014-06-16
131,47,12360,2014-06-17
143,51,12373,2014-06-18
155,55,12387,2014-06-19
167,59,12399,2014-06-20
179,63,12412,2014-06-21
191,67,12426,2014-06-22
203,71,12438,2014-06-23
215,75,12451,2014-06-24
227,79,12465,2014-06-25
239,83,12477,2014-06-26
```

file2.csv

```
Holidays
2010-05-23
2011-06-12
2012-05-27
2013-05-19
2014-06-08
2015-05-24
2016-05-15
2017-06-04
2018-05-20
2019-06-09
2020-05-31
2021-05-23
2022-06-05
2023-05-28
2024-05-19
2049-06-06
2050-05-29
2011-05-24
2011-06-13
2012-05-28
```

And I would like to have the row that matches in the second `CSV`file (in this case it is `2014-06-08`) to be deleted in the created `CSV` file.

Comment: Please, include samples of the input data and the desired output. That way people will have something to work with and it will help to better understand your question.

Comment: Thanks for responding, I've included a picture, hopefully it makes my problem more clear :)

Comment: No, [don't post pictures of textual data,](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) please.

Comment: Since there was not much data on the picture I went ahead and did some OCR on it and replace the image with the text equivalent to help the author. I hope I did it right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a possible solution:

```py
import csv

with open('file2.csv') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    holidays = [_[0] for _ in reader]
    # Skip the header line
    holidays = holidays[1:]

with open('file1.csv') as f, open('output.csv', 'w') as g:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    writer = csv.writer(g)

    for row in reader:
        # Check if the date is in the holidays list
        if row[3] not in holidays:
            writer.writerow(row)
```

Using the sample data provided, the code above will result in the `output.csv` file with the following content:

```
A,B,C,D
11,7,12231,2014-06-07
35,15,12256,2014-06-09
47,19,12270,2014-06-10
59,23,12282,2014-06-11
71,27,12295,2014-06-12
83,31,12309,2014-06-13
95,35,12321,2014-06-14
107,39,12334,2014-06-15
119,43,12348,2014-06-16
131,47,12360,2014-06-17
143,51,12373,2014-06-18
155,55,12387,2014-06-19
167,59,12399,2014-06-20
179,63,12412,2014-06-21
191,67,12426,2014-06-22
203,71,12438,2014-06-23
215,75,12451,2014-06-24
227,79,12465,2014-06-25
239,83,12477,2014-06-26
```